# Ms Sync Framework Partial Participant for a Disconnected environment

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a situation whereby i need to implement the Partial Participant, that is, syncronize data from a central server (sql server) to an (xml, mdf or movable datasouce). This movable datasource will then be copied to a remote location and will be synchronized to a remote server (sql server). Note that i have already implemented the MS Sync Frame work 2 solution for a connected environment using WCF (full proxy participant). 
Any pointers or samples on how i can start for the Partial Participant scenario?

Answer (score 0):

if its not a very big database, you can just sync a SQL Compact database to your central server, send the SQL Compact DB to remote location and sync it with the remote server and vice versa.

Comment: thanks JuneT, will certainly try that solution, it looks feasible